# How to disable the Haptic Feedback when playing a Live Photo

Tags: ios, swift, haptic-feedback, phlivephoto

In my app, I allow the user to play Live Photos from their photo library.

To do this, I use the following:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var livePhotoView: PHLivePhotoView!

@objc func handleTapGesture(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let currentType = currentMediaType {
        if currentType == .livePhoto && livePhotoIsPlaying == false {
            playImageView.alpha = 0
            backButtonView.alpha = 0
            ivePhotoView.startPlayback(with: .full)
            livePhotoIsPlaying = true
        } else if currentType == .livePhoto && livePhotoIsPlaying == true {
            livePhotoView.stopPlayback()
            livePhotoIsPlaying = false
        }
    }
}
```

By using this method, I get Haptic Feedback whenever the Live Photo is played which I don't want. Is this the normal behavior of `PHLivePhotoView`, and is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score -1):

PHLivePhotoViews have an enum property called PHLivePhotoViewPlaybackStyle that determines if the playback should include haptic feedback.

To disable haptic feedback on playback use:

```
livePhotoView.startPlayback(with: .hint)
```

instead of:

```
livePhotoView.startPlayback(with: .full)
```

Comment: This changes what is played completely. The questiion is about removing haptics when playing the full photo.

Comment: Even if one wanted to use `hint` it does not actually disable haptic anyway.